# Similar product price comparison result as per various retailer from product table

Tags: php, mysql

I am using these query. Table name are  wp_pc_products_merchants and wp_pc_products. The name user is inserting in search box. We have split that in array and we have taken in variables as per the position in query.

```
select image,feed_product_name,feed_product_desc,feed_product_image,price,deeplink,id_merchant from wp_pc_products_merchants m,wp_pc_products p  
where m.slug = p.id_merchant and 
feed_product_name LIKE '%$expname[0]%' and 
feed_product_name LIKE '%$expname[1]%' and 
feed_product_name LIKE '%$expname[2]%' and 
feed_product_name LIKE '%$expname[3]%' and 
feed_product_name LIKE '%$expname[4]%' Limit 5 ") 
or die(mysql_error());
```

I am using php and mysql.

It's giving me multiple results from the same retailer and I can say it's giving me similar results.

I need help to display similar products with their respected result once.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
select image,feed_product_name,feed_product_desc,feed_product_image,price,deeplink,id_merchant from wp_pc_products_merchants m,wp_pc_products p  
where m.slug = p.id_merchant and 
feed_product_name LIKE '%$expname[0]%' or
feed_product_name LIKE '%$expname[1]%' or
feed_product_name LIKE '%$expname[2]%' or
feed_product_name LIKE '%$expname[3]%' or
feed_product_name LIKE '%$expname[4]%' Limit 5 ") 
or die(mysql_error());
```